# Stack snippet sub domain and Ajax cors

Tags: support, stack-snippets

Do stack snippets have a subdomain? What is it?

Is there a list of images or icons from that subdomain which I can use in Ajax requests to load images for use in stack snippets?

Comment: http://stacksnippets.net/

Comment: Oh that images thing is importanté, the number of times I've seen or tried to make a jsfiddle that loads some image content (in any manner) and been frustrated that I can't use the exact image that is in production. Snippets I've used very little (mostly on account of not doing web development any more, and snippets doesn't support Unity for some...strange...reason...)